# How to get the body trimmed when loading nodes programmatically?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm getting my nodes directly using `db_query` (I'm applying some specific conditions), so I can't use the [render](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/render/7) function allowing me to get the trimmed (or the summary) version of the body that I configured in the `Manage display` tab of my content type.

For perfomance issue I don't want to use the [node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/7) function on each of my nodes.

Is there a way that I can use a Drupal internal function that would help me to trim the body value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the trimmed summary using [`text_summary()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--modules--text--text.module/function/text_summary/7) which will allow you to pass the text, input format and choose the text size (length) you want.